# Two tags for andrology

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Recently, I created tag [andrology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/andrology). Even more recently, I found tag [male-men-man-boy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-men-man-boy).

1. Should the latter be a synonym of the former?
2. Should [male-men-man-boy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-men-man-boy) be renamed [male](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male) with synonyms [men](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/men), [man](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/man), [boys](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boys) and [boy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boy)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they're synonyms. [male-men-man-boy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-men-man-boy) refers to people of the male gender while [andrology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/andrology) refers to a branch of medicine.

Comment: Do andrology and pediatrics overlap? If so, questions on male children could have tags [tag:andrology] and [tag:pediatrics] instead of the NAMBLA-esque [tag:boy].

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think you're overthinking this. I don't know how you got from andrology to pediatrics, and certainly not to NAMBLA.

Comment: I second that [tag:male-men-man-boy] is unnecessarily complicated, [tag:male] should do just fine.

Comment: @CareyGregory If a male child has, say, testicular problems, which medical specialties will the doctors seeing him come from? My guess would be andrology and pediatrics. Am I wrong? Why?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo And if an adult male has the same problems? Gender and age are two separate things, so there's no reason to link gender to pediatrics. I agree with Narusan that [tag:male] should be just fine and there's no reason for the silly [tag:male-men-man-boy] to exist.

Comment: @CareyGregory Rephrasing, does andrology apply to male children? Or only to males past puberty? Note that there is also [tag:female-women-woman-girl].

Comment: I renamed both of the silly [tag:male-man-men-boy] and [tag:female-women-woman-girl] tags to [tag:male] and [tag:female]. I don't think either one of them need synonyms.